# Retrieving filtered list of files using template toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I would like to retrive the content of files in a directory, which fulfill a given regexp rule or string (e.g. *./*.xml*).

I found following example

```
[% FOREACH directory.files.grep('\.txt$') %]
   ...
[% END %]
```

but do not know how to use it. Could this solve my problem?

Comment: See [`Template::Plugin::Directory`](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Directory.html)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, looked, unfortentlys did not find anything useful...

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? You don't know how to change the regex to match `.xml` files? You don't know how to specify the path to the directory? (The documentation I linked above shows how.) Something else?

Comment: Template::Plugin::Directory return a list of files and directories in a given path, based on path input. I was unable to do: Directory('./*.xml'). I simply get an error (Directory('./') works). Do you know a way to tell Template::Plugin::Directory to return a list of file with a given rule (e.g. *.xml)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation suggests that the output of `directory.files` is a collection of objects, so `.grep()` is unlikely to work. It has methods like `name`, `isdir` and so on.

The simplest solution would be something like:

```
[%- FOREACH file IN directory.files;
        #NEXT UNLESS file.name.match('\.xml$');
        NEXT UNLESS file.ext == 'xml';
        ...
    END -%]
```

Edit: improved answer based on suggestion by [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot).

Comment: Alternatively, since `Template::Plugin::File` provides the [file extension](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/File.html#section_ext), `NEXT UNLESS file.ext == 'xml';`